# Deriving Big Theta From Upper and Lower Bounds

Tags: algorithm, performance, average, big-o

I've calculated that the runtime of my program is:

5 < T(n) < 5n^3+5

How can I derive a big theta from this?  I see the best runtime is a constant 5 and the worst is of n^3, which I believe makes this Ω(1) and O(n^3), but this may be incorrect.  How do I derive the big theta from knowing these bounds?

```
for (i = 0, sum = 0; i < n; ++i)
    for(j = 0; j < n*n; ++j)
        ++sum;
```

PS - I believe my calculation of the lower bound is off, but I'm not too worried about that, as I'm merely asking for an understanding on how to obtain the theta when given this chunk of code.

Comment: To my knowledge, f is only Θ(g) when the function is both Ω(g) and O(g). Saying that f is Θ(g) basically means that f grows at the _same_ rate as g (for big enough n). You would need to figure out tighter bounds, it would seem, if you know that you can express it in big theta notation.

Comment: The best case is of no interest. You need to find upper and lower bounds for the worst case and/or the average runtime, separately. An algo might be Theta(n^2) in the worst case and Theta(n log n) on the average. Normally by default the worst case is meant. When the average time is needed, it is specially mentioned.

Comment: The question literally asks, "For the algorithm below, state the big-theta analysis of the running time in terms of the integer variable n ."  with the problem being (moved up to post).
So whether we're looking for the theta of the worst or average case is not mentioned, I'm assuming the that this is theta(n^3), but that would be based on worst case, correct?

Comment: oh man, I didn't realize the code wouldn't be formatted in the comments :/

Comment: Normally it's the worst case, but for your algorithm it doesn't matter. Your best case analysis is simply incorrect. The running time of this algorithm does not depend on its input (there is no input at all), so the best, the worst, and tge average cases are all the same.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I'm still confused on the how to calculate the best case, I knew it was off when I counted the operations when n = 0, which is 3 I think, so I'm not sure where I went wrong in my calculations.